# Multithreading Creates Multiple Object and Poor Performance Java

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have a code that creates 32 number of threads. The reason that I chose 32 is I have 64 millions entites in database. I want to divide them into 2 millions of pieces and process them in by 500 groups. My thread creating code is below.

```
private void createReportStartTask() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32);

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            service.submit(new ReportStartCreatorTask(sessionFactory.openSession(), 2000000 * i));
        }
}
```

As you can see I created the hibernate session recevies 500 from the list of 2000000 entities and process them in while loop. Then I create a reportStart object and I set reportStart's startId with startCgnatLog id's. After creating and setting reportStart and processing all startCgnatLog elements which have status=false, I re-run the same query to move to other remaning elements from 2000000 list which has status=false. Since startCgnatLog id is unique, I do not expect any multiple reportStart object with same startId.

```
session.beginTransaction();
List<StartCgnatLog> startCgnatLogList = session.createQuery("from ... where status=false").setMaxResults(500).getResultList();
while (startCgnatLogList != null && startCgnatLogList.size() > 0) {
         for (int i = 0; i < startCgnatLogList.size(); i++) {
                  StartCgnatLog startCgnatLog = startCgnatLogList.get(i);
                  reportStart.setStartId(startCgnatLog.getId());
                  session.save(reportStart);
                  startCgnatLog.setStatus(true);
                  session.update(startCgnatLog);
         }

         session.flush();
         session.clear();
         session.getTransaction().commit();
         session.beginTransaction();
         startCgnatLogList = session.createQuery("from ... where status=false").setMaxResults(500).getResultList();
}
```

However, I assume that it is because of multithreading I have nearly 30000000 multiple reportStart object with the samestartId's. How can I solve this issue? and how can I improve my code performance?

Comment: If you start all threads at the same time, they all fetch the same 500 rows from DB. Therefore they all start with the same ID

Comment: All of them are not having the same id's. I'm ensuring that all id's are passed in my for loop which it creates ReportStartCreatorTask. The problem is, there are multiple entities with same id, not all of them has the same id.

Comment: That is then probably because you don't order the data on database side. If you don't order the data, you have no insurance, that the same query always returns the same data

Comment: I know the order it is auto-incremented and starting from 1 and increasing by 1(id).